# Can't write to the file

Tags: perl, file

Why can't I write output to the input file?

It prints it well, but isn't writing to the file.

```
my $i;
my $regex = $ARGV[0];

for (@ARGV[1 .. $#ARGV]){
    open (my $fh, "<", "$_") or die ("Can't open the file[$_] ");
    $i++;
    foreach (<$fh>){
        open (my $file, '>>', '/results.txt') or die ("Can't open the file "); #input file
        for (<$file>){
            print "Given regexp: $regex\nfile$i:\n   line $.: $1\n" if $_ =~ /\b($regex)\b/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Print statement should be `print $file "Given regexp" $reg....`. BTW why do you read data from `result.txt` file? You opened `result.txt` file for writing. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SanketParmar, No, you are correct. I messed up, just still too bad at programming.

Comment: Did you really mean to open `/results.txt` and not, for example, `./results.txt`? Also I don't see any attempt to write anything to that file (though you have a `print` that goes to the console).

Comment: @DavidK, i needed /results.txt, and yes i missed filename near print

Comment: `/` is the root directory. Do you have permission to create files there? If you do not (and I suspect you do not), every attempt to open a new file for writing there will fail. It seemed more likely you would want to create the file in your current working directory, which you would do by naming it `./results.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear whether your problem has been solved.

My best guess is that you want your program to search for the regex passed as the first parameter in the files named in the following paramaters, appending the results to `results.txt`.

If that is right, then this is closer to what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $i;
my $regex = shift;

open my $out, '>>', 'results.txt';

for my $filename (@ARGV) {
  open my $fh, '<', $filename;
  ++$i;
  while (<$fh>) {
    next unless /\b($regex)\b/;
    print $out "Given regexp: $regex\n";
    print $out "file$i:\n";
    print $out "line $.: $1\n";
    last;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wish I could +1 this more than once due to the number of functional and stylistic errors it fixes. Practically every character and newline of difference between this and the originally posted code is a significant lesson.